# Unable to get custom field value from Inventory Adjustment in Netsuite

Tags: netsuite

I'm doing Ns integration ,i have added one custom field(ex:warehouse name) to InventoryAdjustment.And entered and saved some records of InventoryAdjustment.Now i'm trying to get that custom field value. using Java in my application here is the code...Getting null please suggest me how to get custom field value...

```
SearchResult res = _port.search(tsb);
        RecordList rl=res.getRecordList();
        Record[] records=rl.getRecord();

        String salesord=null;

        String date=null;
        for(Record rcd:records){
            salesord=rcd.getClass().getName();
        if(rcd instanceof InventoryAdjustment){
            InventoryAdjustment inv=(InventoryAdjustment)rcd;

            CustomFieldList customFieldList=inv.getCustomFieldList();
                System.out.println(customFieldList);//getting null
                CustomFieldRef[] cfl=customFieldList.getCustomField();

                for(CustomFieldRef customFieldRef:cfl)
                {


System.out.println("........."+customFieldRef.getClass());
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Search does not return all the fields/lists. You can try using get() within a search result to get the complete object. The search() returns the internalid of the object which you can then use in the get()